# Gnuplot condition contour?

Tags: gnuplot, contour

Let's admit that I have 2 imposed  parameters columns X and Y, and for each couple (X,Y) I have a condition that if it is respected Z=1, otherwise Z=0.
I end up with something like

```
    X   Y   Z
    5   0.1 1
    5   0.5 1
    5   0.9 1
    10  0.1 1
    10  0.5 0
    10  0.9 0
```

(With a lot more data X :[5:25] and Y : [0:0.9]). What I want is two separated zones in the parameter space (X,Y) where Z=0 and Z=1. I guess I cannot use 'contour' since the Z value can only be 0 or 1 and the border between the two regions cannot be defined with a specific Z-value.
If I only plot the Z=1 values, I get something like :
[image]

If any one has an idea to only get the contour separating the two regions, I'd love to hear it..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `contour` strategy is not necessarily "doomed". It depends how you want to define the "boundary" which you are interested in. The example below calculates a contour corresponding to level 1 and plots the result together with the original points (I generated points resembling more or less your data). Alternatively, you might for example calculate (with an external tool) the convex hull of points with Z=0 and plot this.

```
fName = 'pnts.dat'
tName = 'contours.dat'

set view map                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
set contour
unset surface                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
set cntrparam linear 
set cntrparam levels discrete 1

set xr [0:0.9]
set yr [5:25]

set isosamples 1000,1000
set table tName
splot fName
unset table
unset contour

set terminal pngcairo
set output 'fig.png'
unset key

p \
    tName w l lw 4 lc rgb '#666666', \
    fName u 1:($3==1?$2:1/0) w p ps 0.5 pt 7 lc rgb 'red'
```

this gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your final result does ressemble what I what. However, when I do this i get the error : "test.gnu", line 15: warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range
"test.gnu", line 15: z axis range undefined or overflow. Line 15 being the splot line.

Comment: Actually, replacing splot fname with splot fname u 2:1:3, I get the error :  warning: Cannot contour non grid data. Please use "set dgrid3d" even if my columns have the same size.. I don't get it.

Comment: @DamienGagnier sorry, I forgot to mention that I used gridded data, i.e., if there are M distinct x-values and N y-values, the file I used has MxN data lines and individual blocks corresponding to a particular x-value are separated with a blank line... - the [faq](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-320003.9) items 3.9 and 4.16 cover this in more detail.